# How to count data for the last month?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to count data for the last month. How can I achieve this? Subqueries in SELECT clause and correlated subqueries are not allowed. Something similar to this:

```
count(crimes.crime_id) OVER (PARTITION BY ((crimes.month::date - interval '1 month')::date), crimes.category) AS "Previous month crimes"
```

But that doesn't work and selects by current month:

```
    Crime category     |   Month    | Previous month crimes | Current month crimes
-----------------------+------------+-----------------------+----------------------
 anti-social-behaviour | 2021-01-01 |                     1 |                    1
 bicycle-theft         | 2021-01-01 |                    19 |                   19
 bicycle-theft         | 2021-02-01 |                     4 |                    4
 bicycle-theft         | 2021-03-01 |                    18 |                   18
 burglary              | 2021-01-01 |                    61 |                   61
 burglary              | 2021-02-01 |                    42 |                   42
 burglary              | 2021-03-01 |                    48 |                   48
 criminal-damage-arson | 2021-01-01 |                    60 |                   60
 criminal-damage-arson | 2021-02-01 |                    54 |                   54
 criminal-damage-arson | 2021-03-01 |                    64 |                   64
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    crimes.category AS "Crime category",
    crimes.month AS "Month",
    count(crimes.crime_id) OVER (PARTITION BY ((crimes.month::date - interval '1 month')::date), crimes.category) AS "Previous month crimes",
    count(crimes.crime_id) OVER (PARTITION BY crimes.month, crimes.category) AS "Current month crimes"
FROM crimes
WHERE crimes.month >= :start_month AND crimes.month <= :end_month
GROUP BY crimes.month, crimes.category, crimes.crime_id
ORDER BY crimes.category, crimes.month ASC;
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS crimes(
    "crime_id" bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    "category" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "persistent_id" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "month" DATE NOT NULL,
    "location" bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES locations (location_id),
    "context" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "id" bigint NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    -- "location_type" location_type NOT NULL,
    "location_type" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "location_subtype" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "outcome_status" bigint REFERENCES outcomes (status_id)
);
```

Sample data for crimes table:

```
 crime_id |       category        |                          persistent_id                           |   month    | location | context |    id    | location_type | location_subtype | outcome_status
----------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+------------------+----------------
        1 | anti-social-behaviour |                                                                  | 2021-01-01 |    56047 |         | 89873829 | Force         |                  |
        2 | bicycle-theft         | 197505c1b681339abd93e87200b9d68779d08e0b89154f3568cf13615b0e3147 | 2021-01-01 |    39811 |         | 89921014 | Force         |                  |              1
        3 | bicycle-theft         | 403ecf74716180b5d4d8f64d6c96cf05351684c0dc924f0d520331ed559697b2 | 2021-01-01 |    57734 |         | 89905063 | Force         |                  |              1
        4 | bicycle-theft         | 8f04c99ded0a5ab35d8d48037c1a8230c8bf06226f5f09a5d45fb914572460d1 | 2021-01-01 |    57735 |         | 89941994 | Force         |                  |              1
        5 | burglary              | 340ae50ef443ba7df87f0a69ff80fc8aa2dd46500d40ef8696baa4f3dac7de57 | 2021-01-01 |    57736 |         | 89934048 | Force         |                  |              1
        6 | burglary              | 7f85d33e112a93702c54f6d9b101b5fc2962cc30fcd6aca59991fa8a00df5fb6 | 2021-01-01 |    56114 |         | 89936322 | Force         |                  |              2
        7 | burglary              | e3e609ace7096d5b9f7b68a5c3d26653dc79f6d5d6f22c959f99654cc67ee61a | 2021-01-01 |    57734 |         | 89936709 | Force         |                  |              1
        8 | burglary              | 46cf1c8597841acc963b525b70d4f3c2bbee0977b97b7a059e94762cab350ab5 | 2021-01-01 |    57699 |         | 89894592 | Force         |                  |              1
        9 | burglary              | 517f7c304d89b92f8cbf429b4d873bb456768148e566c53f4f31a772d277ddcf | 2021-01-01 |    57737 |         | 89902228 | Force         |                  |              1
       10 | burglary              | 6e12fbf5ee3a56a4a75f0fb91f5008c1ac8e6f18ab74c62f789739208491e208 | 2021-01-01 |    57705 |         | 89930518 | Force         |                  |              3
```

Comment: Please append part of your sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle (with minimal data)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6e66f32eab9eb71ae4b9b516909b504d)

Maybe something like this. Remove `crime_id` from `GROUP BY`, so that the simple aggregate is per month/category.  Then use window functions to obtain the prior `count` per `category`, based on the month ordering.  COALESCE simply handles the `null` cases (for rows with no prior month) by returning 0.  The `DISTINCT` is not required, unless you're not selecting enough detail to identify each group properly.  I'm removing that.

Remember, if your `WHERE` clause eliminates monthly data you need for `LAG` to find previous months counts, you can filter later, after the `LAG` calculation.  In other words calculate current and previous results first (with a slightly larger date range, or no range), then filter those results by the final date range required, using CTE terms or a derived table.

```
SELECT
    crimes.category AS "Crime category",
    crimes.month AS "Month",
    COALESCE(LAG(count(crimes.crime_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY crimes.category ORDER BY month), 0) AS "Previous month crimes",
    count(crimes.crime_id)       AS "Current month crimes"
FROM crimes
WHERE crimes.month >= :start_month AND crimes.month <= :end_month
GROUP BY crimes.month, crimes.category
ORDER BY crimes.category, crimes.month ASC
;
```